# MaterialUI: how to position items inside grid item?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What would be the best way when working with MaterialUI to position an image inside a `<Grid item>`?

This could just be done by putting a div in the grid item, making it 100% width/height, applying flexbox, then do align-items and justify-content but I think that defeats the whole purpose of the Grid system, I'm thinking it shouldn't be that much code to position something inside the Grid.

example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-lamport-rvrm5?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main benefits of Grid is you have:

1. Flexible Grid system with 12 col
2. Responsiveness
3. React-style syntax (props)
4. Custom layout with `CSS flex` syntax

But deep down its still using `CSS flex` for layout

If it were CSS, to center an element inside a div container, you just need to:

1. Make the container `display: flex`
2. Add `justify-content: center` to container

With that in mind, we can translate to Grid with

```
  {/* Lets try to center the photo */}
  <Grid item container xs={6} justify="center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="placeholder"></img>
  </Grid>
```

`container` is to add `display: flex` to Grid

`justify="center"` is to add `justify-content: center` to Grid

Output:

[image]

No more className and more React props.